# Scala: it is possible to use generic type at runtime?

Tags: scala

i wonder if i can change the implementation of such a method:

```
def foo() {
   val json : String = ; // get json from somewhere
   val jsonAst = new String(json).parseJson // or JsonParser(source)
   val msg = jsonAst.convertTo[UserDetails]
```

}

so i can provide the "UserDetails" as parameter

so calling foo will be something like:

```
foo[UserDetails]()....
```

by the way:

convertTo signature is:

```
def convertTo[T :JsonReader]: T = jsonReader[T].read(this)

trait JsonReader[T] {
   def read(json: JsValue): T
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you do `new String(json)` before parsing?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just declare your function the same way:

```
def foo[T : JsonReader] = { 
  ...
  val msg = jsonAst.convertTo[T] 
}
```

**UPDATE** To elaborate, since there appears to be some confusion in the comments. `def foo[T : JsonReader]` does *not* mean that it accepts only subclasses of `JsonReader`. That declaration is actually equivalent to this: `def foo[T](implicit jsonReader: JsonReader[T])`

Comment: too bad ... Care to elaborate?

Comment: i guess the reason is UserDetails is a case class & you wrote the "T" as parameter of a class that inherits JsonReader, but it should pass as generic type into jsonAst.convertTo[UserDetails]...

Comment: Don't guess. Just show what the actual error says. (No, this syntax does not mean that it inherits JsonReader).

Comment: i get: Error: Cannot find JsonReader or JsonFormat type class for T
          val msg = jsonAst.convertTo[T]

Comment: Yes, you need an implicit instance of `JsonReader[UserDetails]` in scope for it to work. Try looking at your original (unparametrized) implementation and figuring out where the implicit comes from.

Comment: i didn't understand your solution can you give an example?

Comment: example of what?

Answer (score 0):

Dima's solution should be working, but your implementation of convertTo seems strange. I think it should be something like :

`def convertTo[T :JsonReader]: T = implicitly[JsonReader[T]].read(this)`

Comment: `jsonReader` is probably just a method that does something like `def jsonReader[T: JsonReader] = implicitly[JsonReader[T]]`